# Why app is not asking for requested location permission?

Tags: react-native, expo

What im trying to do is to ask the user for location permission, and if the user doesn't allow the permission, cannot navigate to other screens.
I have used `expo-location` for this, and when I test the app locally, it asks me to allow or not allow the permission for the location, but when I generate an APK, to test it on android, it shows me the alert that I dont have the location permission, and when I go to the app setting to allow it manually, it says `No permission requested`

```
  function requestLocationPermission() {
    return Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync().then((handleResponse) => {
      if (handleResponse.status === 'granted') {
        setLocationPermission(handleResponse.status);
      } else if (handleResponse.status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Map/Gps needs the appropriate permissions.');
        return Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      }
    });
  }


  useEffect(() => {
       requestLocationPermission();
      buttonText();
  }, [locationPermission]);

  const confirm = () => {
    if (locationPermission === "granted") {
      navigation.navigate('CreateProfile',
    } else {
      requestLocationPermission();
    }
  };
```

So, in the APK it returns me: `alert('Map/Gps needs the appropriate permissions.');`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you declared the appropriate permissions for you Android API level in AndroidManifest.xml as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions)?

Comment: I don't have an  AndroidManifest.xml, the app is running on expo only